# CakePhp AngularJs pagination

Tags: angularjs, pagination, cakephp-2.0

I started learning CakePhp and AngularJs, I want to get pagination working.

I found this simple tutorial: http://florian-kraemer.net/2015/10/cakephp-angularjs-pagination/ but I can't get it to work.

This is the code from the example:

```
public function index() {

    $query = $this->Table->find();
    if (empty($this->request->params['paging'][$this->Table->alias()])) {
       $paging = false;
    } else {
       $paging = $this->request->params['paging'][$this->Table->alias()];
    }
    $this->set('records', $this->paginate($query));
    $this->set('paging', $paging);
    $this->set('_serialize', ['records', 'paging']);
}
```

My Model is called Entry, how to I have to change the code for this example to work, I tried it like this but it's not working:

```
public function index() {

    $query = $this->Entry->find();
    if (empty($this->request->params['paging'][$this->Entry->alias()])) {
       $paging = false;
    } else {
       $paging = $this->request->params['paging'][$this->Entry->alias()];
    }
    $this->set('records', $this->paginate($query));
    $this->set('paging', $paging);
    $this->set('_serialize', ['records', 'paging']);
}
```

I am not sure what to change in my code to get it working. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks, Gregor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this code, it should be work. You have to declare $paging after paginate.

```
public function index() {

    $query = $this->Entry->find();
    $this->paginate($query);
    if (empty($this->request->params['paging'][$this->Entry->alias()])) {
       $paging = false;
    } else {
       $paging = $this->request->params['paging'][$this->Entry->alias()];
    }
    $this->set(compact('records', 'paging'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['records', 'paging']);
}
```